# Swap button with image when user click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want that when user click on button then page method call by Ajax then i want to swap the button with a animated image. show me the best way to do it. i know how to Swap button with image. here one sample.

```
$('the-button').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="/wherever.jpg"/>');
});
```

i do not know that how to maintain image position where the button is located on page.
basically i want to show animated image at the place of button when user click on it and ajax call start and when ajax call finish then animated image will be replaced with button again.

here i am giving one demo url **demo.aspnetawesome.com**

please show me the best way to achieve my goal which will be highly reusable. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have two elements, the button and the image. make the button visible and the animated image hidden (with display: none so that it doesn't occupy any space in the page). Then, when the button is clicked, hide the button and show the image.
If you use display: none then provided the button and the image are the same size and rendered adjacent in the DOM they will consume the same place and not affect your layout.

So very roughly:

```
var animation = $('#the-image');
var button = $('#the-button');

button.on('click', function(){
  button.hide();
  animation.show();
});
```